# Using Gabor filter on an image

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm looking to write some code in opencv/matlab that'll apply the Gabor filter to images to spot interesting image regions. I've read quite a lot of literature and seen some of the previous matlab/opencv code, but I'd like to attempt it all myself to make sure I fully understand.

I have the equation for the Gabor function and an image. I am unsure of the steps I should take in my algorithm. The general idea I got was to take the discrete Fourier transform of the image, multiply it (convolve?) it with the Gabor function then take the inverse Fourier transform for the result. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int ks = 47;
int hks = (ks-1)/2;
int kernel_size=21;
double sig = 7;
double th = 200;
double ps = 90;
double lm = 0.5+ps/100.0;
double theta = th*CV_PI/180;
double psi = ps*CV_PI/180;
double del = 2.0/(ks-1);
double sigma = sig/ks;
double x_theta;
double y_theta;

Mat image = imread("C:\\users\\michael\\desktop\\tile1.tif",1), dest, src, src_f;

if (image.empty())
{
    return -1;
}

imshow("Src", image);

cvtColor(image, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);
src.convertTo(src_f, CV_32F, 1.0/255, 0);
if (!ks%2)
{
    ks+=1;
}

Mat kernel(ks,ks, CV_32F);

for (int y=-hks; y<=hks; y++)
{
    for (int x=-hks; x<=hks; x++)
    {
        x_theta = x*del*cos(theta)+y*del*sin(theta);
        y_theta = -x*del*sin(theta)+y*del*cos(theta);
        kernel.at<float>(hks+y,hks+x) = (float)exp(-0.5*(pow(x_theta,2)+pow(y_theta,2))/pow(sigma,2))* cos(2*CV_PI*x_theta/lm + psi);
    }
}


filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel); 
imshow("Gabor", dest);
Mat Lkernel(kernel_size*20, kernel_size*20, CV_32F);
resize(kernel, Lkernel, Lkernel.size());
Lkernel /= 2.;
Lkernel += 0.5;
imshow("Kernel", Lkernel);
Mat mag;
pow(dest, 2.0, mag);
imshow("Mag", mag);

waitKey(0);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you express your idea in code, or at least pseudo-code? It is hard to see where the gaps are in your understanding with the paragraph of text

Comment: are you asking, how to use a gabor filter in opencv ?

Comment: @berak No, not specifically, the question is more along the lines of what steps should the algorithm take.

Comment: @NeilSlater This is where I'm unsure. From the literature, I understand that you take the DFT of the image, and multiply it with the Gabor function. I'm not sure how to do that step - how exactly would the multiplication happen? Do they mean convolve the DFT of the image with the FT of the Gabor function? I can't find any literature that gives a nice step by step of how this is implemeneted. Many thanks

Comment: @MikeMiller: Implement it the way you think (either one of the ideas in your comment), if it doesn't work, post here and ask for help. It is easier to fix broken code than discuss in English in the abstract. And it looks like this should only be a few lines in matlab either way

Comment: @NeilSlater Does the pseudo-code sound right, though? I'm not a very proficient coder - a few lines to you could be a few hours to me! :)

Comment: @MikeMiller: I don't know, but if the question was clearer I could probably figure it out. I've not coded the Gabor filter, but have coded other image filters and worked with FFT. What I do when not sure: Prototype it in a short Matlab script, plot it and compare with a known result. Chances are if I got the order of FFTs or types of multiplication wrong, the code would either error due to matrix size mismatch or it would just look totally wrong. If I was completely stuck then, I'd ask for help, but if I had time I'd tinker with the code to see it was close.

Comment: @NeilSlater OK, thanks Neil. I'll give it a shot and see what I come up with.

Comment: @NeilSlater I've added some code I'd been working on with the help of some code I'd looked at previously. I think I'm comfortable with creating the Gabor kernel and convolving it with the image using filter2D, but the code from LKernel onwards - I'm unsure of what it does.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C++ API for Matlab (or opencv), so I cannot figure out exactly what is going on in your code. I hope someone else can see it.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for taking a look - appreciate it